# What are the advantages/disadvantages of the Masque and the Axe?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When you do the quest a Deadra's Best Friend, you get 2 choices of getting the axe or the masque. What are the advantages and disadvantages of both items?

Answer (score 3):

To start with, The [Masque of Clavicus Vile](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Masque_of_Clavicus_Vile) is the true daedric artifact, and the only one of the two that counts towards the [Oblivion Walker](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Oblivion_Walker#Achievements) achievement. It also has one of the best benefits of any headgear for dealing with vendors.

The [Rueful Axe](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Rueful_Axe) on the other hand, is a two-handed battleaxe that *may* have a higher base damage than most of the weapons you can find/make depending on how early you do the quest. Unfortunately the enchantment on the axe is not particularly amazing (20 points of damage to stamina). The weapon has a speed of 0.5, which is slower than even warhammers.

Comment: So in short, the Masque is an advantage and the Axe is the disadvantage :)

Comment: I think the weapon which you get from Malacath has even more power than the rueful axe

Comment: Yeah, it's not the greatest weapon in the game by any stretch, but the power is about on par with glass/ebony (if you ignore the lowered speed, which generally don't start turning up until lvl 27/36 (while Barbas shows up around Falkreath for the quest around lvl 10) Although if you take into account the speed, it's about on par with a Dwarven warhammer, which is lvl 12-ish.

Comment: Does the Axe swing faster when using Elemental fury?

Comment: Elemental fury doesn't work if you have an enchanted weapon equipped. You get a "this weapon already has an enchantment" message.